# Slow touch response

Tags: screen, touchscreen, performance

My girlfriend bought a Lenovo K6 with Android 6 a few months ago. After some time, I tried to use her phone and I notice that the touch responsiveness was very slow. I feel a delay in every touch (open app, keyboard, screen scroll, etc).

I tried to uninstall some apps and upgrade to Android 7 but nothing change. The curios thing is that the problem not happens in the screen where we need to put the password before load the Android (after a restart), so  I think that is software a problem.

I'm almost doing a hard reset in her phone to see if the problem is resolved. Before I do that someone have any idea how resolve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that the zoom was activated in her phone... this is the cause of the slow touch response. To turn off:

1. Open your device's **Settings**
2. Tap **Accessibility**, then tap **Magnification gestures**
3. At the top, tap the **Off** switch